# In a translation of a classic math book: is the term *normal* translated correctly? Is there a better term?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definition

I am reading an English translation of the classic book by Gelfond & Linnik:  Elementary Methods in the Analytic Theory of Numbers.

Here is the definition of "normal" from the book (page 5 in my copy):

> We shall describe the system of numbers $H\subset[0,n]$ as *normal*
>   if, for any numbers $f \in$
>   $[1,n]$;$f'\in[1,n]$;$f\notin(H)$;$f'\notin{H}$, we have $f + f' - n$
>   $\notin H.$

Is this the standard term to describe this situation?

I looked it up in Wikipedia and [found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal) a list of where *normal* is used mathematically.  None of the uses listed there seemed to fit the use of Gelfond & Linnik.

If *normal* is not the standard term, what would be the standard term?